# how to install this libs for qmake lib error?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I creare a hello program with this code follow this [document](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Core_with_Qt-Embedded#Develop_Qt_Application):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        QApplication app (argc, argv);
        QPushButton button ("Hello world !");
        button.show();
        return app.exec();
}
```

but, qmake command has error.

> root@ubuntu:/home/fgit/helloqt# make arm-linux-g++
>   -Wl,-rpath-link,/tmp/FriendlyARM/nanopi2/libs/usr/lib -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib -o helloqt main.o    -L/tmp/FriendlyARM/nanopi2/libs/usr/lib
>   -L/usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib -lQtGui -L/usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib -L/tmp/FriendlyARM/nanopi2/libs/usr/lib -lQtNetwork -lQtCore -lpthread  /opt/FriendlyARM/toolchain/4.9.3/lib/gcc/arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.3/../../../../arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.bfd:
>   warning: libts-1.0.so.0, needed by
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so, not found
>   (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>   /opt/FriendlyARM/toolchain/4.9.3/lib/gcc/arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.3/../../../../arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.bfd:
>   warning: libz.so.1, needed by
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so, not found
>   (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to `deflateInit_'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to`deflateInit2_'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to `compress'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtCore.so: undefined
>   reference to`uncompress'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to `deflate'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtCore.so: undefined
>   reference to`compress2'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to `deflateEnd'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to`crc32'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to `inflate'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to`inflateInit2_'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to `inflateInit_'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to`ts_read_raw'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to `inflateEnd'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to`ts_open'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to `ts_fd'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to`ts_config'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to `inflateReset'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to`deflateReset'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to `ts_close'
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
>   reference to`ts_read' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Makefile:103: recipe for target 'helloqt' failed make: *** [helloqt]
>   Error 1 root@ubuntu:/home/fgit/helloqt#

I have this lib in my ubutu.
(I have x64 ubuntu14.04 and install the compuler from that document and also install qtcreator,qtdeclarative5-dev) 
How to solve these errors?

Comment: You'll need to link with `zlib` apparently. Try putting `-lz` to linking options

Comment: you mean I wrote "make -lz" ?

Comment: @MHM no, `make -lz` is not what you should do. Editing the Makefile and adding `-lz` to the linker options is what you should do.

Comment: I add -lz to this file directry : gedit /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/mkspecs//qws/linux-arm-g++/qmake.conf and all -lz and -lts like this `QMAKE_CC = arm-linux-gcc -lts  -lz QMAKE_CXX = arm-linux-g ++ -lts  -lz QMAKE_LINK = arm-linux-g ++ -lts  -lz QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB = arm-linux-g ++ -lts -lz` but errors occures again.